# 'Expression' parameter data types for user-defined functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a function that takes as a parameter an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx) like what is used with [BINARY_CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx). Specifically, I want my parameter to be a list of 1 to N column names. When I look at the definition of BINARY_CHECKSUM (or MAX or CHECKSUM for that matter) in Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio the parameter is defined as 'Expression (any type)'- can a user-defined function emulate this? I know that I could use a parameter a delimited list of comma names, but I'm curious about 'Expression (any type)'.

Comment: A UDF that accepts a variable number of arguments? I believe that's not currently possible.

Comment: I agree- I am certain that a UDF can't accept a variable number of arguments. However, I am intrigued by the implementation of the 'Expression (any type)' parameter. Take a look at the documentation of the CHECKSUM function to see what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)
declare @columns varchar(max), @table_name sysname

set @table_name = 'sys.objects'
set @columns = '*'

set @cmd = 'select top 1 binary_checksum('+@columns+') as column_name from '+@table_name
print @cmd
exec (@cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really trying to understand the internals. Maybe this link will be more illustrative: http://t.co/cK9DIU1z

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own aggregate functions (like `BINARY_CHECKSUM`, `COUNT`, etc) in SQL Server 2005 or later, you'll have to use the CLR. See the following on MSDN:

[How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
[CREATE AGGREGATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)