# T-SQL - stored procedure that would handle an unknown number of parameters of unknown types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a large number of stored procedures that basically do the same thing: get a list of values as parameters, then go to some table and SELECT all the rows WHERE these values match.

I would like to be able to have a single stored procedure that would be able to handle all these cases.

How would you tackle this?

Comment: What is the point of even using a stored procedure for this? It will need dynamic SQL so you won't benefit from plan caching or ownership chaining. Just have a separate stored procedure for each case.

Comment: Don't think you can currently have a single sproc with a variable number of formal parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653405/expression-parameter-data-types-for-user-defined-functions - perhaps codegen via T4 or similar

Comment: @Martin Smith - my current stored procedures use dynamic SQL anyway (they have to). So I would like to have a more maintainable code.

Comment: Why don't you have a proc that executes the varchar parameter that you send to it? ;)

Comment: @rapt "dynamic SQL anyway (they have to)" - I bet they don't HAVE to.

Comment: How about having just one XML input parameter, which you would unwrap within the sproc to extract whatever criteria? Then stick a subset of your data into a table variable, and use CASE or IF / THEN statements within the sproc to pare down the subset to get what you need?

Comment: @Dan Andrews - My worldview is that the developer is one of the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use XML based approach for your problem. Send an XML as an input parameter. Convert the xml into a table. From the table form dynamic query and execute it in order to achieve your desired functionality.  See the below example. In this example Departments is a table which contains 3 columns pkDepartmentId (int), DepartmentName (varchar) and BuildingNumber (int). Using this approach you can send n Number of parameters and their values as input parameters.

pkDepartmentId  DepartmentName  BuildingNumber
1   Electronics and Communication   1
2   Computer Science    2
3   Instrumentation and Technology  4

```
--EXEC TestProc '<Parameters>
--                  <Param>
--                      <ColumnName>pkDepartmentId</ColumnName>
--                      <ColumnValue>1</ColumnValue>        
--                  </Param>
--                  <Param>
--                      <ColumnName>DepartmentName</ColumnName>
--                      <ColumnValue>Electronics and Communication</ColumnValue>        
--                  </Param>
--                  <Param>
--                      <ColumnName>BuildingNumber</ColumnName>
--                      <ColumnValue>1</ColumnValue>        
--                  </Param>    
--              </Parameters>'

CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
@parameters XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp1 TABLE
    (
          ColName VARCHAR(100)
        , ColVal VARCHAR(4000)      
    )

    INSERT INTO @temp1
    SELECT    Params.Col.value('ColumnName[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') ColName
            , Params.Col.value('ColumnValue[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') ColVal              FROM   @parameters.nodes('//Parameters/Param') Params(Col)

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Departments WHERE '

    SELECT @sql = @sql  + ColName + ' = ''' + ColVal  + ''' AND '
    FROM @temp1

    -- Trim last AND
    SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 3)

    PRINT @sql                  

    EXEC (@sql)             

END
```

On executing this proc following result is obtained
pkDepartmentId  DepartmentName  BuildingNumber
1   Electronics and Communication   1

Comment: I don't see `ColumnType` in the XML and in the `DECLARE @temp1 TABLE` table? Also, you build the `@sql` string in such a way that makes it vulnerable to SQL injections, what if I actually want to `DECLARE` the variables that I retrieve from the XML so I could use them in the `@sql` string, so I could build something like `@sql = 'SELECT * FROM Departments WHERE id = @id AND firstName = @firstName'`?

Comment: Hi Rapt, i have modified the code to remove the ColumnType. In case you want to declare variables and use them to build the sql string then you might have to use a cursor or while loop to loop through all records in @temp Table.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it. You are going to throw all database performance down the drain. T-SQL and code reuse don't mix.

What you *can* do though is to have all these stored procedures generated automatically. There are many tools that do this, and you can easily roll your own: use SQL itself to extract the table definition into XML, then use XSLT to transform this into T-SQL and generate the proc. It can be automated into your project build and contiguous integration process. This way you get the best of both worlds: strongly types, efficient T-SQL code, yet an agile, DRY and maintainable process that makes it easy to re-write all those 100s of procs with one single change.

Comment: What kind of reuse are you against? Dynamically creating SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

How about using table valued parameters TVP (provided your SQL Server version is >= 2008) ? This doesn't solve the "unknown types" part though. I guess you would have to use varchar(max) or even nvarchar(max) and then cast it as necessary...

See: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

For older versions of SQL Server, see also:

- http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html
- http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html

Answer (score 0):

default parameters:

```
create procedure MyPRoc1
(
@param1 int,
@param2 int =1
)
as
begin
    --code
end
```

you can call it using

```
exec MyPRoc1 10
```

or

```
exec MyPRoc1 1,1
```

Comment: Not my case - because you are assuming an upper bound on the number of parameters, plus you are assuming a specific type for each optional parameter.

Comment: well about the number of parameters you can easily add new parameters when necessary with the default option that it wont break the process. Regarding the variable type of parameters that's tough you would have to make them all varchar and then treat them as you need inside the procedure. I would recomend but that's the only option, there isnt a "variable" datatype in SQL